# FetchedResultsController objects lose Relationships while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a custom ViewController managing a TableView with a FetchedResultsController.

When my view is loaded everything seem to work fine (the cells contain the right data), however after scrolling the view the cells that get bind again with the data from the FetchedResultsController but the relationships of some objects are now set to nil.

*controllerWillChangeContent* and *controllerDidChangeContent* are not triggered during the scrolling.

This is the code in my view controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tb cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ClaimProductCell";
ClaimProductTableViewCell *cell = (ClaimProductTableViewCell*)[tb dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelItems = [[self productCellLoader] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
}

[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
ClaimProduct* claimProduct = (ClaimProduct*)[[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
ClaimProductTableViewCell* productCell = (ClaimProductTableViewCell*)cell;
productCell.indexPath = indexPath;
[productCell bindWithClaimProduct:claimProduct];
}
```

Here it follows the table view cell binding code:

```
- (void)bindWithClaimProduct:(ClaimProduct*)claimProduct
{
DocumentProduct* documentProduct = claimProduct.claimProductToDocumentProduct;
Product* product = documentProduct.documentProductToProduct;


self.addButton.hidden = YES;

self.productCode.text = product.code;
self.quantityLabel.text = [documentProduct.qty stringValue];
self.nameLabel.text = product.descriptionName;
self.documentCode.text = documentProduct.documentProductToDocument.code;

NSDate * date = documentProduct.documentProductToDocument.date;

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];

self.documentDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld/%ld/%ld", (long)[components day], (long)[components month], (long)[components year]];

// product image
NSString* imagePath = [ImagePathUtility imagePathFromImageName:product.image imageCode:product.code imageType:kImageProduct];
[self.productImageView setImageWithPath:imagePath placeholderName:kProductPlaceholderImage];
}
```

If I close and open again the app the view controller correctly shows the cells. If I scroll them I get the same problem again.

I am using Xcode 5 and working on an old project that does not use ARC.

[EDIT] This is NSFetchedResultsController lazy instantiation code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController
{
if (_fetchedResultsController)
    return _fetchedResultsController;

NSManagedObjectContext* mainContext = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ClaimProduct" inManagedObjectContext:mainContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"claimProductToDocumentProduct.documentProductToProduct"]];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"claimProductToDocumentProduct.documentProductToProduct.code" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"claimProductToClaim == %@", [self claim]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:mainContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[fetchRequest release];
[sortDescriptor1 release];
[sortDescriptors release];

return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

[EDIT 2] I noticed another error that arises when looping on the [self.fetchedresultscontroller fetchedObjects]. The object in the relationship seems to be non nil, however its properties are all nil. This is the portion of code:

```
- (void)updateTotals
{
NSArray * claimProducts = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];

NSDecimalNumber * imponibile = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
NSDecimalNumber * lordo = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];

for (ClaimProduct * claimProduct in claimProducts) {
    if (![claimProduct.qty isEqualToNumber:@0]) {
        //compute totals
        NSDecimalNumber * unitPrice = [claimProduct.claimProductToDocumentProduct.price decimalNumberByDividingBy:claimProduct.claimProductToDocumentProduct.qty];
        NSDecimalNumber * claimProductPrice = [unitPrice decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:claimProduct.qty];
        imponibile = [imponibile decimalNumberByAdding:claimProductPrice];


        NSDecimalNumber * unitPriceLordo = [claimProduct.claimProductToDocumentProduct.totalprice decimalNumberByDividingBy:claimProduct.claimProductToDocumentProduct.qty];
        NSDecimalNumber * claimProductPriceLordo = [unitPriceLordo decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:claimProduct.qty];
        lordo = [lordo decimalNumberByAdding:claimProductPriceLordo];
    }
}
...
}
```

Here the claimProductToDocumentProduct relationship is not nil, however sometimes it happens that its properties are nil and I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in *decimalNumberByAdding*.

Comment: are u sure there's actually a relationship?  except having indexPath property on a custom cell, nothing's too weird.. i'd change your NSFetchRequest sort descriptor ascending value to make sure behavior is consistent..

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with the NSFetchedResultController lazy instantiation.

Comment: okay, since you seem to be suggesting it breaks when you scroll down and I'm saying it may be because the relationships are actually nil, change your sortDescriptor1 ascending value to NO and see what happens

Comment: Could it be that the object in the relationship is a fault and its properties are set to nil?https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html

Comment: if that's the case you need to execute an NSFetchRequest to get the relationship object by using this predicate [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", managedObject.relationshipObject]